# Android contact list, error in Asynctask and setAdapter

Tags: javascript, java, android, listview, contacts

I am trying to make a gps app with a contact list to link up with other people, I am new to android studio, so I am not sure how to solve this. I created the map and gps first, and they work fine, but now the contact list has an error.

My contactlist is in a popup menu that can be accessed with the contacts button on the homepage, but now theres always an error when trying to access the contactslist

The error i got from the log is : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

Here is the mainactivity

```js
 package com.example.pow.gpsapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;


import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.example.pow.gpsapp.SelectUser;
import com.example.pow.gpsapp.SelectUserAdapter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


 public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
     ArrayList<SelectUser> selectUsers;
     List<SelectUser> temp;
     ListView listView;
     Cursor phones, email;

     ContentResolver resolver;

     SelectUserAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        Button btnContact= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnContact);
        btnContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
               showSortPopup(MapsActivity.this,null);
           }
        });
    }
     private void showSortPopup(final Activity context, Point p)
     {
         selectUsers = new ArrayList<SelectUser>();
         resolver = this.getContentResolver();
         listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);

         phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
         LoadContact loadContact = new LoadContact();
         loadContact.execute();


         // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
         RelativeLayout viewGroup = (RelativeLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.ContactLayout);
         LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.contactlist, viewGroup);

         // Creating the PopupWindow
         final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
         popup.setContentView(layout);
         popup.setWidth(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         popup.setHeight(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         popup.setFocusable(true);

         // Some offset to align the popup a bit to the left, and a bit down, relative to button's position.
         int OFFSET_X = -20;
         int OFFSET_Y = 95;

         // Clear the default translucent background
         popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
         // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.
         popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, OFFSET_X, OFFSET_Y);

         Button Back = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
         Back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 popup.dismiss();
             }
         });


     }
     public void onZoom(View view)
     {
         if(view.getId() == R.id.btnzoomin)
         {
             mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);
         }
         if(view.getId() == R.id.btnzoomout)
         {
             mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(8), 2000, null);
         }
     }

    public void onSearch(View view)
    {
        EditText location_tf = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
        String location = location_tf.getText().toString();
        List<Address> addressList = null;
        if(location != null || location.equals(""))
        {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
            try {
                addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Address address = addressList.get(0);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude() , address.getLongitude());
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker"));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(1.3468, 103.9326);
        CameraUpdate location = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 15);
        mMap.animateCamera(location);
    }
     class LoadContact extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
         @Override
         protected void onPreExecute() {
             super.onPreExecute();

         }

         @Override
         protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
             // Get Contact list from Phone

             if (phones != null) {
                 Log.e("count", "" + phones.getCount());
                 if (phones.getCount() == 0) {
                     Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "No contacts in your contact list.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }

                 while (phones.moveToNext()) {

                     String id = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
                     String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                     String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                     String EmailAddr = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA2));
                     String image_thumb = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI));


                     SelectUser selectUser = new SelectUser();
                     selectUser.setName(name);
                     selectUser.setPhone(phoneNumber);
                     selectUser.setEmail(id);
                     selectUser.setCheckedBox(false);
                     selectUsers.add(selectUser);
                 }
             } else {
                 Log.e("Cursor close 1", "----------------");
             }
             //phones.close();
             return null;
         }

         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
             super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
             adapter = new SelectUserAdapter(selectUsers, MapsActivity.this);
             listView.setAdapter(adapter);

             // Select item on listclick
             listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                     Log.e("search", "here---------------- listener");

                     SelectUser data = selectUsers.get(i);
                 }
             });

             listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
         }
     }

     @Override
     protected void onStop() {
         super.onStop();
         phones.close();
     }
}
```

AndroidManifest

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pow.gpsapp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

SelectUser.java

```js
package com.example.pow.gpsapp;


public class SelectUser {
    String name;


    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    String phone;

    public Boolean getCheckedBox() {
        return checkedBox;
    }

    public void setCheckedBox(Boolean checkedBox) {
        this.checkedBox = checkedBox;
    }

    Boolean checkedBox = false;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    String email;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }


}
```

SelectUserAdapter.java

```js
package com.example.pow.gpsapp;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.pow.gpsapp.R;
import com.example.pow.gpsapp.SelectUser;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class SelectUserAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public List<SelectUser> _data;
    private ArrayList<SelectUser> arraylist;
    Context _c;
    ViewHolder v;

    public SelectUserAdapter(List<SelectUser> selectUsers, Context context) {
        _data = selectUsers;
        _c = context;
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<SelectUser>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(_data);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return _data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return _data.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) _c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = li.inflate(R.layout.contactview, null);
            Log.e("Inside", "here--------------------------- In view1");
        } else {
            view = convertView;
            Log.e("Inside", "here--------------------------- In view2");
        }

        v = new ViewHolder();

        v.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        v.check = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
        v.phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.no);

        final SelectUser data = (SelectUser) _data.get(i);
        v.title.setText(data.getName());
        v.check.setChecked(data.getCheckedBox());
        v.phone.setText(data.getPhone());



        view.setTag(data);
        return view;
    }

    // Filter Class
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        _data.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            _data.addAll(arraylist);
        } else {
            for (SelectUser wp : arraylist) {
                if (wp.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText)) {
                    _data.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView title, phone;
        CheckBox check;
    }
}
```

activitymaps.xml

```js
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="133dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtAddress"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_Address" />

        <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search"
        android:id="@+id/btn_Address"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:onClick="onSearch"

            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="^"
        android:id="@+id/btnzoomin"
        android:onClick="onZoom"

        android:layout_below="@+id/txtAddress"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contextClickable="false" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="v"
            android:id="@+id/btnzoomout"
            android:onClick="onZoom"

            android:layout_below="@+id/txtAddress"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnzoomin" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Contact"
            android:id="@+id/btnContact"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtAddress"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnzoomout" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.pow.gpsapp.MapsActivity" />

</LinearLayout>
```

contactlist.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:id="@+id/ContactLayout">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/contacts_list"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnBack" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back"
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

contactview.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:weightSum="3">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="2.6"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:text="User name"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/no"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Phone no."
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/check" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

```js
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                          at com.example.pow.gpsapp.MapsActivity$LoadContact.onPostExecute(MapsActivity.java:202)
                                                                          at com.example.pow.gpsapp.MapsActivity$LoadContact.onPostExecute(MapsActivity.java:158)
                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6075)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: making listview public and final may can help!

Comment: `ListView` is initialized, then `AsyncTask` is executed. Hmmm. Have you tried putting in logs inside the `doInBackground()` or `onPostExecute()` for the size of your `selectUsers` ?

Comment: @pooyan The ListView is already a global variable, if he makes it `final`, he won't be able to modify it anymore.

Comment: @Adnan The `ListView` was initialized before executing the `LoadContact` `AsyncTask`.

Comment: @RyanPow Do check the size of the value for your `selectUsers`. An NPE can also be encountered if the objects list passed to your adapter is empty. Do post an update after you've checked.

Answer (score 0):

In your `activitymaps.xml` you do not have `ListView` with `contacts_list` id.

**Edit**

according to what i see in your code i think your problem will be solved if you change your "showSortPopup" first lines as bellow:

```
     // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
     RelativeLayout viewGroup = (RelativeLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.ContactLayout);
     LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.contactlist, viewGroup);

     selectUsers = new ArrayList<SelectUser>();
     resolver = this.getContentResolver();
     listView = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);

     phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
     LoadContact loadContact = new LoadContact();
     loadContact.execute();
```

Comment: Do avoid using exclamation points since it seems quite rude when answering in the community.

Comment: That's true. There is no contacts_list in activitymaps.xml 
I agree @pooyan

Comment: @RyanPow Can you post your `activity_maps.xml`? Since in your post, we can only see the `contacts_list ListView` in your `contactlist.xml`.

Comment: @Adnan he attach "activity_maps" layout to his fragment that dose not have list view with id of "contacts_list " and after that he try to get list view with id of "contacts_list " from "activity_maps". so it will return null. am i wrong?

Comment: @Adnan pooyan may possibly be right. Since in Ryan Pow's code, he is initializing the `ListView` with just `findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);`. This is only checking the layout of the activity itself.

Comment: The first fragment is for the GPS map and i tried to get the contacts_list from the showSortPopup, so am i suppose to separate these  2? The ListView is in contactslist.xml, so I'm supposed to declare on 2 pages? Sorry im really new to this

Comment: @Ryan 
You can inflate the view.
`LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.contactlist.xml,null);
 listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);`

Comment: @pooyan i still get error after changing the code from the answer, i'm still getting java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

Comment: @RyanPow you should mention that you should call 'loadContact.execute();'  and also 'listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);' after showing popup.

Comment: @pooyan it still wont work, i added 'loadContact.execute();' and 'listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);' under                                       // Creating the PopupWindow
         final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
         popup.setContentView(layout);
         popup.setWidth(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         popup.setHeight(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         popup.setFocusable(true);

Comment: @RyanPow just for testing, comment all the line inside 'showSortPopup' function except the line of code that is needed to show popup, and see if your popup is working or not.